# Get Lua running with Torch on Windows 10 (with limited admin rights)

Tags: lua, installation, deep-learning, torch, zerobrane

> Setting up Deep Learning Framework [Lua, Torch]:

I need to set up **Lua** running with **Torch**
on **Windows 10** and the **ZeroBrane IDE**, with limited possibilities of installing Software and restricted download rights.

It took me so Long, so I thought I might share a recipe for you guys. I would be glad if it helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [SETTING UP](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLuaInWindowsForNewbies)

1. (Admin) Download/Install tdm64/gcc/5.1.0-2.exe Compiler
2. (Admin) Download/Install ZeroBrane (Lua IDE)
3. Download lua/5.3.4.tar.gz (https://www.lua.org/download.html)
4. Write batch file build.cmd

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: you may change the following variable's value
:: to suit the downloaded version
set lua_version=5.3.4
set work_dir=%~dp0
:: Removes trailing backslash
:: to enhance readability in the following steps
set work_dir=%work_dir:~0,-1%
set lua_install_dir=%work_dir%\lua
set compiler_bin_dir=%work_dir%\tdm-gcc\bin
set lua_build_dir=%work_dir%\lua-%lua_version%
set path=%compiler_bin_dir%;%path%

cd /D %lua_build_dir%
mingw32-make PLAT=mingw

echo.
echo **** COMPILATION TERMINATED ****
echo.
echo **** BUILDING BINARY DISTRIBUTION ****
echo.

:: create a clean "binary" installation
mkdir %lua_install_dir%
mkdir %lua_install_dir%\doc
mkdir %lua_install_dir%\bin
mkdir %lua_install_dir%\include

copy %lua_build_dir%\doc\*.* %lua_install_dir%\doc\*.*
copy %lua_build_dir%\src\*.exe %lua_install_dir%\bin\*.*
copy %lua_build_dir%\src\*.dll %lua_install_dir%\bin\*.*
copy %lua_build_dir%\src\luaconf.h %lua_install_dir%\include\*.*
copy %lua_build_dir%\src\lua.h %lua_install_dir%\include\*.*
copy %lua_build_dir%\src\lualib.h %lua_install_dir%\include\*.*
copy %lua_build_dir%\src\lauxlib.h %lua_install_dir%\include\*.*
copy %lua_build_dir%\src\lua.hpp %lua_install_dir%\include\*.*

echo.
echo **** BINARY DISTRIBUTION BUILT ****
echo.

%lua_install_dir%\bin\lua.exe -e"print [[Hello!]];print[[Simple Lua test successful!!!]]"

echo.

pause
```

---

> SETTING UP TORCH UNDER LUA ON WINDOWS

--- Quick and dirty ---

1. Download and unzip the desired binary build from: https://github.com/hiili/WindowsTorch
2. Generate user.lua file in C:\Users\Name.zbstudio:

   ```
   path.lua = [[C:\app\tools\torch\bin\luajit.exe]]
   ```
3. Move the C:\app\tools\torch\lua folder to C:\app\tools\torch\bin

--- Untested alternatives ---

Not tested, but I encourage you: https://github.com/torch/torch7/wiki/Windows#cmder
Maybe second best option is to build a virtual environment with linux

Note: More information on Torch can be found here
https://github.com/soumith/cvpr2015/blob/master/cvpr-torch.pdf

---

> GET STARTED WITH LUA AND TORCH

http://torch.ch/docs/tutorials.html
I recommend Torch Video Tutorials to get the basics straight (https://github.com/Atcold/torch-Video-Tutorials)

This is a Torch Cheetsheet for further reading (https://github.com/torch/torch7/wiki/Cheatsheet):
- Newbies
- Installing and Running Torch
- Installing Packages
- Tutorials, Demos by Category
- Loading popular datasets
- List of Packages by Category

Comment: You don't need admin privileges to install ZeroBrane Studio, as you can simply decompress the zip installation archive for Windows. Also, you'll need [torch7](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBranePackage/blob/master/torch7.lua) plugin for the IDE.

Comment: Thank you for contributing. Nice work around for ZeroBrane IDE.