# How to install Torch on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, lua, torch, zerobrane

I try to install Torch on Windows 10 using [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277220/get-lua-running-with-torch-on-windows-10-with-limited-admin-rights). I followed most steps without any problems, but stumbled here:

```
Generate user.lua file in C:\Users\Name.zbstudio: 
path.lua = [[C:\app\tools\torch\bin\luajit.exe]]
```

The latest version of Zero Brane Studio doesn't create '.zbstudio' subfolder in 'C:\Users\'. Instead there's a 'zbstudio' subfolder inside an installation directory (app.lua and config.lua lie there by default). I tried to place user.lua in this subfolder, but it didn't help.

Without this step Torch isn't accessible and 'th' command doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there it a typo in the instructions; it should be `C:\Users\<username>\.zbstudio` folder. You don't need to guess or know the location of that folder, as if you navigate to `Edit | Preferences | Settings: User` menu in the IDE, it will open the correct location for `user.lua` file where you can put your settings.