# Problems in Lua and Torch installation, and importing libraries

Tags: lua, torch, luarocks

I never used **Lua**, and I need to run scripts from this [repository](https://github.com/frantiz96/amar)

I followed instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277220/get-lua-running-with-torch-on-windows-10-with-limited-admin-rights) 
to install **Lua interpreter** and **Torch** (I'm working on Windows). But then I had problems installing the required libraries through **luarocks**, so running the scripts I have some errors at very first "*require ...*" lines.

I also tried to install **Torch** on **Google Colab**, and then to run scripts using [lutorpy](https://github.com/imodpasteur/lutorpy), again with no success.

So I would be very grateful, if you can provide me some instructions to correctly set all the Lua stuffs and run these scripts. Sorry but I am very new in this kind of stuffs. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you already have most of your environment set up, it may be much easier to correct `some errors at very first "require ..." lines.` than to start from scratch. It appears that the script you are running can't find libraries installed with luarocks, so you need to figure out where those are installed and set [package.path](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.path) and [package.cpath](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.cpath) variables to point to luarocks environment. The error message contains the list of directories being searched, so you can use that as a check in case you add your directories incorrectly.